# Microsoft Teams Angular application, Sinon Stub `microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess`

Tags: angular, microsoft-teams, sinon

I'm currently working on a Microsoft Teams Angular application, and testing the Microsoft Teams library.

I'm trying the test the call below with SinonJS but have had no luck. Is there an efficient way to test that `microsoft.authentication.notifySuccess` was called with the param of `token`?

```
microsoftTeams.initialize(() =>
  microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess({token} as any)
);
```

I'm looking for something like

```
 sinon.assert.calledWith(microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess as sinon.SinonStub, {token});
```

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This is the bit I was missing, we need to tell sinon to take in a 
// function/callback and immediately call it.
sandbox.stub(microsoftTeams, 'initialize').callsFake((callback) => callback());
sandbox.stub(microsoftTeams.authentication, 'notifySuccess');

// Run code and assert
sinon.assert.calledWith(microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess as sinon.SinonStub, {token})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess` by a sinon spy. This simply works with `sinon.spy()`. Afterwards you can check with `sinon.assert` if this spy was called with a certain argument.

```js
// Replace function with a spy
let spy = sinon.spy(microsoftTeams.authentication, 'notifySuccess');

// Call method under test
microsoftTeams.initialize(() =>
  microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess({token} as any)
);

// Check spy call
sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, {token});
```

Hope this helps. Best regards